# Date.Now not displaying 12 hour format

Tags: vb.net

I know this probably is considered a repeat question so I will apologize in advance, but I have looked at question after question and everyone says the "hh" will display a 12 hour format.  I keep getting a 24 hour format as if I have "HH".  What gives?

```
strTime = Date.Now.ToString("hhmmsstt")
```

Comment: Thought it must be a "culture" thing, but I couldn't duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

HH is 24 hour format while hh is 12 hour one

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.  I am looking for 12 hour format, but the code I posted above with "hh" is giving me 15:06:40 PM.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

On this link you can check all the possible time formats, so you are interested about the following:

"h"

The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.

More information: The "h" Custom Format Specifier.

"hh"

The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

More information: The "hh" Custom Format Specifier.

"H"

The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.

More information: The "H" Custom Format Specifier.

"HH"

The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

More information: The "HH" Custom Format Specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
strtime = Format(Now, "hh:mm tt")
```

You get an output like this

```
04:33 PM
```

If for something you dont want the 0 behind 4 you just take out one h

```
strtime = Format(Now, "h:mm tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
strTime = Date.Now.ToLocalTime()
```

to get a local time.